# How do I extract a single byte from within a string on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In Android, I can extract a single byte from within a string using code like the following:

```
byte[] arrByte = String.getBytes(); .
```

If I wanted to do this on the iPhone in Objective-C, how could I accomplish the same task?  Additionally, how could I get a byte for a given index in the string?

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the [`NSString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) reference you will get various methods to get the data from a string. An example is

```
NSData *bytes = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can also make use of the method `UTF8String`

Comment: Note that a character might likely be multiple bytes.